# ggplot producing smaller boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that holds data like this:

```
Variant variable    value
1         I  Flutter 76.14708
2         I  Flutter 76.23548
3         I  Flutter 76.07839
4         I  Flutter 76.29594
5         I  Flutter 76.25026
6         I  Flutter 76.27906
7         I  Flutter 76.23952
8         I  Flutter 76.18824
```

The R code for the plot is as follows:

```
mydata <- read.csv("NBAccuracy.csv",header=TRUE)
dfm <- melt(mydata, id.var = "Variant")
dfm
ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Variant),width=0.5)+ xlab("Dataset") + ylab("Accuracy(%)")
```

However, the size of the boxplots are too small and need to find a way to scale them up

[image]

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue on your graph is related to some variables with a small standard deviation (in your example, it seems that most of your values for Flutter variant I is close to 76)

One possible way to scales up those values, is to facet your graph by using `facet_wrap` to scale up those values too small:

```r
df <- data.frame(variant = rep(c("I","II","III"), each = 300),
                 variable = rep(rep(c("Flutter","MyTracks","ThreeNow"), each = 100), 3),
                 value = c(rnorm(100, mean = 76, sd = 1),
                           rnorm(100, mean = 60, sd = 15),
                           rnorm(100,mean = 75, sd = 25)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variant))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]